# What are the fonts / template used by Foreign Affairs in this document?

Tags: fonts, templates

Apologies if this is not the right forum to ask this question.  I'm astonished with how beautiful this document is: http://jeffsachs.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Why-Nations-Fail_Sachs-Review.pdf.

I was hoping somebody could give me their best guess as to the font of the following:

- The Foreign Affairs logo
- Each of the fonts used in the title, subtitle, author name, and Volume Number
- Body text

Is there a template that is widely available that would allow me to recreate this?

Comment: [`pdffonts`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppler_(software)#poppler-utils) can do the same...

Comment: this is rather off topic for this site at least the part about which fonts are in this document. you should look in the document properties as it will list most of the fonts in a pdf (the logo is not actually text so the font in not listed). as for the template, I don't think there is one available that matches that one but it doesn't look that complex so you should be able to recreate fairly easily.

Comment: AkzidenzGroteskBE-Bold, BigCaslon, BigCaslon-Rom, Calibri, FACaslon-Italic, FACaslon-Regular, FACaslonExpert-Regular, VanDijckMT-Italic,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two screenshots showing the **pdf document properties**. There is a section with the fonts.

[image]

[image]